# TypeError : kick() takes 1 positional arguement but 2 were given

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have been facing this issue recently, and I have no idea why. When I try to kick ANYONE, it doesn't work at all! It's the same with the ban command too. It just gives me an error here. I even have all the perms in my bot and gave it the mod role too, what is the problem here?

Here's the code :

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
  if reason == None:
    reason = "No reason provided."
  try:
    await member.send(f"It seems you have been kicked out of {ctx.guild.name} by {ctx.author.name}.\nPossible reason : {reason}")
  except:
    await member.kick(member)
    await ctx.send(f'User {member} has been kick. Possible reason : {reason}')
#
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
  if reason == None:
    reason = "No reason provided."
  try:
    await member.send(f"It seems you have been banned from {ctx.guild.name} by {ctx.author.name}.\nPossible reason : {reason}")
  except:
    await member.kick(member)
    await ctx.send(f'User {member} has been banned. Reason : {reason}')
```

Please do answer my question if you can, even attempt it... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I `Member.kick`, there's no need to pass the `Member` argument.

```py
await member.kick()
```

Also I see that in the ban command instead of actually banning the member you're simply kicking it, to properly "ban" him/her use:

```py
await member.ban()
```

Comment: I didn't fully understand you... Also, yeah, I just copy-pasted kick command here so I forgot to write ban. but what are you trying to say by "no need to pass the Member arg." If I won't pass the arg in ctx area, how will the bot ban?

Comment: I don't mean that, I mean that you don't have to pass `member` into `member.kick`, it's already defined, so `member.kick(member)` won't work but `member.kick()` will

Comment: Just do this: `member.kick(reason=<your reason variable>)` and same with the ban. This is a discord coroutine.